# Fixed column name in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a problem:
I'm doing automated pivots monthly development created from different tables. Some contain at least one entry for each month, some don't. The ones that are missing the month (one of the months is simply not written in the month column) then also don't show up in the created PivotTable. I don't want to add any artificial rows to the source data. So my question is, is there any way to use vba to create a fixed list of column labels, to which I can then associate the data from the months column of the source data, so that all months are displayed, even those without records.

Have this:

[image: 1]

Want this:

[image: 2]

I have already tried a solution via creating a pivot from the data model, however I need the source to still be the actual source data, not some external data.
Another option was to create a relation between the source table and another one with all the months, however this didn't work either and even when I put the list of months from the other "auxiliary" table into the columns in the pivot, the months columns without relevant data were hidden again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a full calendar table, then your solution with the auxiliary table containing all months is the right one.

In the data model, you shall then link it to all your month columns in other tables and use it in pivot tables as you already tried (you should ideally hide month columns from other tables in Power Pivot).

But then, what remains to be done is to right-click on the pivot table => "Pivot table options...", go within tab "Display" and check "Show items with no data on columns".

[image: Show items with no data on columns]

Comment: You can only use relationships if the pivot is loaded from the data model but it can still be linked to the source in your sheet. Just use data > load from table to load the sheet data into powerquery. then close/load to data model to get it in the datamodel. If the source is update you just need to refresh the pivot to update the data in the data model.

Comment: @ceci, That's the problem, I just want the pivot table to still be linked to the main data table. However, when I use this method (from data model) I can't even click on the source data the source data icon is greyed out.
Can you please explain me in more detail how to do this?

Comment: That's normal as a pivot related to data model has access to all tables in the data model. The link is Table in Sheet > load to powerquery > download to dataModel > use in Pivot. when you refresh the pivot he will go to the source to get the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Attached a working [demo file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jisxk6s0ymxa3l06jk3jx/Pivot-with-dataTbl.xlsx?rlkey=g9kpi1wqw2u9ncqtqstcy2gau&dl=0). You can add data in the col on the left and refresh the pivot. for the users it'll be like if the pivot is directly connected to the table.

To reproduce:

1. The table on the left is your source => click data > load from table
2. This will open PowerQuery => Home > close and load (click on the arrow) > close & load to.
3. Choose connection only + check "load to data model".

once back in excel go to the data model, generate a calendar table, add the relationship.

Insert pivot based on your data from your table but use the "month nr" of the date table instead. Make sure to set the pivot options (post above) to show rows/cols with no data.

Note: Once you get used to using a data model and date table you'll never go back. You now have "most" dax functions at your disposal in Excel like for calculating Year to date , R12, ... or adding complex slicers etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating, however after clicking on what I get the option to click on "Connection only"?

Otherwise the link to the calendar does not work for me. In the source data I either have only the month numbers (can't create a relationship there) or I have the whole data there, but after linking to the calendar it still doesn't work unfortunately... I have to create a help sheet, but that's not such a problem. In the end, converting to VBA and automation looks the worst. It's obvious that this language is not really built for working with data models...

Comment: is the demo I shared working for you? The link with the date table should be your date, showing only the months is defined afterwards when you just drag the month (from the calendar table) into your pivot table.

Comment: Yes, linking already works for me, I had to do it using a different column, but it works. Thanks. However, as I mentioned, I didn't find, for example, a way to use VBA to create this calendar in the data model (without having to create it on a new sheet)... But I'm definitely closer to the goal than before. :)

Comment: Once in the data model you can add a date table by using the button => Design > Date table > New. No need for vba. Alternatively, mainly in Excel, to get more control on this table you'll start using Powerquery to generate date tables but to start the standard is fine.

Comment: Yes, I understand, But the whole point of this is automation of specific processes where you don't have to do anything manually, except inserting data... But I'm almost there :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Automating is kind of my day to day activity so surely I understand. What I don't understand is the manual part in the discussed process, once setup you just need to update your data and hit the refresh button. Nevertheless, good luck!